# Extending an image across entire screen

Tags: html, css

I'm created a sitemap for a website I'm developing and I'm having some trouble stretching a background image across the entire screen as shown in this screen shot. [Screenshot](http://img.ctrlv.in/504fb3d6eb5dd.jpg)

As you can see, there is a border along the right side and the bottom that I'm trying to get rid of. The markup I'm using is

```
#sitemap {
background-image:url(images/gradient-sitemap.png);
position: relative;
left: -10px;
top: -1px;
width: 100%;;
height: 225px;
```

}

Comment: It would be nice to see your HTML as well as a direct like to the gradient-sitemap image, can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: When you set the width to 100%, that becomes the width of the screen. But since you start in left:-10px, a 10px gap appears on the right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove all from your body tag and HTML

```
html, body{margin:0px; padding:0px border:0px}
```

Answer (score 1):

set the width to 101% and the height to something more than the current 225px